# RabbitMQ: is internal delivery (between exchanges) guaranteed?

Tags: java, rabbitmq

Assuming I have single host RabbitMQ server and settings like below:

```
                  .--------------.
               .->| EX fanout    |
.-----------.--'  | "monitoring" |
| EX fanout |     '--------------'      .----.
| "common"  |--.  .-----------.      .->| Q1 |
'-----------'  '->| EX direct |--q1--'  '----'
                  | "queues"  |--q2--.  .----.
                  '-----------'      '->| Q2 |
                                        '----'
```

When I send message to exchange "common" with routing key "q1" - is it guaranteed that message reach Q1 queue?
I want to make sure such message wont get stuck somewhere between exchanges or between exchange and queue.